# Upgraded python to 3.9 on Ubuntu 20.04 and now certain packages don't work

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, matplotlib

I was using Python 3.8, and needed to upgrade to Python 3.9. I installed, and set the default to Python 3.9.

```
user@user-desktop:/usr/lib$ python3 --version
Python 3.9.5
```

I'm trying to import matplotlib, but it's giving me this error:

```
usr@user-desktop:/usr/lib$ python3
Python 3.9.5 (default, Nov 23 2021, 15:27:38) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import matplotlib
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 113, in <module>
    from . import _api, _version, cbook, _docstring, rcsetup
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/rcsetup.py", line 27, in <module>
    from matplotlib.colors import Colormap, is_color_like
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/colors.py", line 51, in <module>
    from PIL import Image
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 69, in <module>
    from . import _imaging as core
ImportError: cannot import name '_imaging' from 'PIL' (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PIL/__init__.py)
```

I've tried the following:

```
user@user-desktop:/usr/bin$ pip uninstall PIL
WARNING: Skipping PIL as it is not installed.
user@user-desktop:/usr/bin$ pip uninstall Pillow
Found existing installation: Pillow 7.0.0
Not uninstalling pillow at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages, outside environment /usr
Can't uninstall 'Pillow'. No files were found to uninstall.
```

I tried installing them, since they weren't there.

```
user@user-desktop:/usr/bin$ pip install PIL
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PIL (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for PIL
user@user-desktop:/usr/bin$ pip install Pillow
Requirement already satisfied: Pillow in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (7.0.0)
```

I tried the same with pip3, and python -m pip and no luck.

From some other StackOverflow posts, I've set a static link between python3.9 and python3 by doing:

```
sudo ln -s python3.9 /usr/bin/python3
```

but I'm not sure that worked, taking a look at usr/bin/python:

```
user@user-desktop:/usr/bin$ ls -l python*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      25 Sep  8 06:24 python3 -> /etc/alternatives/python3
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 5494584 Nov 14 07:59 python3.8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      33 Nov 14 07:59 python3.8-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.8-config
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 5803968 Nov 23  2021 python3.9
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      16 Mar 13  2020 python3-config -> python3.8-config
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     384 Mar 27  2020 python3-futurize
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     388 Mar 27  2020 python3-pasteurize
```

When I use python3.8, I can install all of these modules just fine. Any help?

Comment: Don't replace the system Python on Linux/macOS. Period. It's the *system* Python for a reason. Packages need to be recompiled (those that are compiled in the first place) when the minor version changes. Along the same lines, don't try to upgrade, downgrade, uninstall, or change the system packages. Your personal packages should be in your user directory, *completely separate* from the system. Don't use `sudo` unless you know *exactly* what you're doing and what the consequences of your actions are.

Comment: Multiple versions of Python can live quite happily next to each other on the system, so long as the system version is in place. Don't relink `/usr/bin/python` or `/usr/bin/python3` to anything other than what it was installed as. Just call 3.9 when you want to use it as `python3.9`, or make an alias of it.

Comment: @MattDMo Okay, it doesn’t look like it linked, so I don’t need to undo anything, right?

Comment: You mentioned you set the default to 3.9. Do the same process, but set it back to 3.8 and see if things work again.

Comment: Just alias python3 to python3.9?

Comment: You said in your first sentence that you "*installed, and set the default to Python 3.9.*" How did you do that - using `apt`?

Comment: If I set it back to python3.8, it works, but I want python3.9 to be able to import matplotlib. I don’t believe aliasing python3 to python3.9 would work since I tried importing matplotlib within python 3.9 as seen in the code snippet.

Comment: I installed python 3.9 using apt. Then did sudo update-alternatives —config python3. Then selected the python3.9 option.

Comment: Just run `sudo update-alternatives —config python3` and choose 3.8. You'll need to use `pip` to install packages for 3.9. They'll be separate from 3.8.

Comment: @MattDMo The problem is that I need python3.9 for a library I’m using, so choosing 3.8 in update-alternatives won’t allow me to use a function in that library. Are you saying to do python3.9 -m pip install xxxx?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Like I said, you can have any number of Python versions installed side by side, but they each will have their own package installations. So, if install 3.7, 3.9, and 3.10, and you want to use `matplotlib`, you'll have to install it individually for all of them. They can't share.

Comment: No prob. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For others who had this issue, all I needed to do was upgrade Pillow using
`python3.9 -m pip install Pillow --upgrade`.